# Actualizar una imagen ya cacheada en el navegador con vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, quasar

Estoy usando vue y vuex donde obtengo la imagen de un perfil de esta forma uso [quasa](https://quasar.dev/)

Necesito poder actualizar la imagen ya que esta contiene una que fue cargada anteriormente, no logro hacerlo ya que el navegador al parecer me la tiene cargada y la cachea.

Nota:

> cropSuccess

Es el metodo encargado de subir la imagen

```
<q-item-section avatar>
                        <q-avatar
                            size="80px"
                            color=""
                            text-color="white"
                            class="shadow-2 bg-deep-orange-2"
                        >
                            <q-img
                                ref="logos"
                                :src="logo"
                                spinner-color="white"
                                style="min-height: 80px"
                            >
                                <template v-slot:error>
                                    <div
                                        class="absolute-full flex flex-center"
                                        style="background-color: #cccc"
                                    >
                                        <q-avatar
                                            color="grey"
                                            text-color="white"
                                            icon="image"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </template>
                            </q-img>
                        </q-avatar>
                    </q-item-section>

export default {
   computed: {
        logo() {
            return (
                `/storage/business/${this.business.business_id}/logo_${this.business.business_id}.png`
            );
        },
   },
   methods: {
       cropSuccess(data, field, key) {
            this.$store.commit("auth/CHANGELOGO", data);
                this.$store.state.simulator.refresh++;
            
        },
   }


}
```

Comment: Para evitar este tipo de problema, cuando la imagen cambia pero no su `URL`, lo que suelo hacer es guardar un "indice de versión" y concatenarlo a la `URL` de la imagen. Ejemplo: `logo_${this.business.business_id}.png?v=${image_version}`. De esta forma consigo avisar al navegador que la imagen cambio y mantener las ventajas de cache mientras esto no pasa.

Comment: @Marcos Pero como le diria yo la version ?v=${image_version} en el metofo computado

Comment: Así como ya le estás pasando `this.business.*`, pásalo dentro de dicho objeto.

Comment: Mmm @Marcos no me quedo clara la respuesta.

Comment: No sé cómo explicarlo para que se entienda. Otra opción es agregar el `timestamp`. Ejemplo: `image.png?t=${Date.now().getTime()}`. Eso sí... no más cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción para evitar que el navegador busque la imagen en su cache es agregando a la `URL` de la imagen el [`timestamp`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_temporal) via [`query param`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let url = `image.png?t=${(new Date()).getTime()}`;
console.log(url);
```

Cada vez que se ejecute el código, la variable `t` tendrá un nuevo valor, lo que para el navegador significa una **nueva `URL`**.

---

**Nota:** Esta estrategia no es recomendable para el `front-end` público, ya que previene el cache y provoca que la imagen tenga que ser descargada cada vez que se visita la página.

Comment: Gracias.. por la respuesta.